# Kotlin - How to get time ("HH:mm") from string Date

Tags: kotlin

How can I get the time from a json where I have values like:

```
"time": ["1507457400000", "1507458600000"] //Strings
```

In **Javascript** I could do something like

```
new Date(1507457400000)             // return Sun Oct 08 2017 12:10:00 GMT+0200
new Date(1507457400000).getHours()   // return 12
new Date(1507457400000).getMinutes() // return 10
```

But I have no idea how to get the time using kotlin. Any idea what is the best way to get the time from the data I have?

Comment: If you're targeting the JVM 8, you can work with the `java.time` API. To answer more precisely, we would need to know exactly what you mean by "get the time". Do you want the date as well? Do you want an object or a formatted string?

Answer (score 2):

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Date((1507457400000 / 1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = 1507457400000
    val date = calendar.time
```

if you have the millisecond in a string like `str`:

```
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = str.toLong()
    val date = calendar.time
```

for hour and min:

```
    val h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    val result = h.toString() + ":" + m.toString()
```

Comment: Well, I just need the time(hh:mm) and now your code returns me: Sat Oct 07 10:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017 any idea to get just the time, thanks @mtak

Comment: @gon250 Your Javascript example didn't get the time either. Please update your question with more details as to what kind of value you expect

Comment: @gon250 Isn't this what you want?